# Sum of two vectors pointing to the embedded n-sphere

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Consider the embedded n-sphere $\mathbb{S}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, is the set created by

$$
\mathbb{X} = \{ \mathbf{x}_1 + \mathbf{x}_2 : \mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{S}^n, \mathbf{x}_2 \in \mathbb{S}^n \}
$$

equal to the ball of radius 2, i.e.

$$
\{ \mathbf{r} : \mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}, |\mathbf{r}| \leq 2 \}
$$

and if it is so; is there some simple way to show that this is true?

Comment: Have you tried showing this via set inclusion? That is, show that $r \in \mathbb{X} \Longleftrightarrow r \in$ ball of radius 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

If $v_1,v_2\in S^n$, then $\|v_1+v_2\|\leqslant\|v_1\|+\|v_2\|\leqslant1+1=2$.

On the other hand, let $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $\|v\|\leqslant2$. You want to prove that you can write $v$ as $v_1+v_2$, where $\|v_1\|,\|v_2\|=1$. If $\|v\|=0$, this is trivial. Otherwise, let $w_1=\frac v{\|v\|}$. The norm of $w_1$ is equal to $1$. Let $w_2$ be an unitary vector orthogonal to $w_1$. You can write$$v=\|v\|w_1=(\alpha w_1+\beta w_2)+(\alpha w_1-\beta w_2),$$where $\alpha=\frac{\|v\|}2\leqslant1$ and $\beta\in\mathbb R$. Then$$\|\alpha w_1\pm\beta w_2\|=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}.$$Now, pick $\beta$ such that $\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}=1$; in other words, $\beta=\pm\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$. Thus, $v$ is written as a sum of two elements of $S^n$.

---

Here's another way of proving this statement. It is clear that, if $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is such that $\|v\|=2$, then $v$ can be written as the sum of two unitary vectors $1$ ($v=\frac12v+\frac12v$). If $\|v\|=0$, then $v$ can also be written as the sum of two unitary vectors (pick *any* unitary vector $w$; then $0=w-w$). Now suppose that the statment is false, that is that there is a vector $v$ (with $\|v\|\in(0,2))$ which *cannot* be written as the sum of two unitary vectors. Then, if $v'$ is another vector with the same norm, then $v'$ also cannot be written as the sum of two unitary vectors. Indeed, let $f$ be a linear isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $f(v')=v$. Then, if $v'=w_1+w_2$ with $\|w_1\|,\|w_2\|=1$,$$v=f(v')=f(w_1)+f(w_2)$$and $\bigl\|f(w_1)\bigr\|=\bigl\|f(w_2)\bigr\|=1$. Therefore, the set $S^n+S^n$ contains vectors with norm $2$ and contains the null vector (whose norm is $0$), but contains no vector with norm $\|v\|$. Therefore $S^n+S^n$ is disconnected. But this is impossible, since $S^n$ is connected and the addition is a continuous map.